# How can I properly test the official 7" Touchscreen?

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I received my two 7" Touchscreen display units yesterday and hooked them up as instructed.  The screen works wonderfully, but I cannot get touch inputs to register.  I'm sure there must be a driver I need to load, or a program I should run to try to test, but so far firing up a Kivy demonstration did not register the touch events so I'm concerned my first-run units are faulty.

I am on the latest copy of raspbian (via apt-get upgrade) but my bootloader is likely from May.

**What is needed to properly test the official 7" Touchscreen?**

Comment: It probably won't do any harm to do a sudo rpi-update to ensure you have the latest version of firmware.  I wouldn't have thought it would be necessary if you have done a update/upgrade, but who knows.

Comment: Ah hah!  I updated the firmware and it worked as expected.  It would be nice to know if there's a particular kernel module or test tool to ensure it is working with all ten touch inputs, though.

Comment: Can not help with that, do not have the device.  I do not remember seeing anything about a test suite though.

Answer (score 1):

TMWILSON 26 referred me to this [link](https://github.com/derekhe/wavesahre-7inch-touchscreen-driver). It's a 'custom driver' which works with a lot of touch screens. This got the touch screen working for me in X, not in Kivy yet.

Hope this helps.